# Input field blur event not get triggering while set display none for parent element in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input field within my Div element. I have focus the textbox using mouse. 
While press any keys, i will hide the div element using display: none
While the elements gets hide, blur event for input element triggers in chrome But blur event not triggering in Firefox and IE browsers.

For your reference please run the below sample.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWDH988538TX

Steps to reproduce:

Run the sample. Open the console window
Focus the textbox using mouse.
While the cursor is placed within textbox, click any keys.
Check the console. Blur event will trigger.

**But this not working in Firefox**

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWDH988538TX working for me on Firefox60.0.2

Comment: Have you follow the reproducing steps correctly?Open the console and then Focus the textbox using mouse- > click enter key -> Check console (In both firefox and chrome)

Comment: yes, You are right, I noticed that in firefox you have to click outside

Comment: My version firefox 62.0.3

Comment: Other browsers, without clicking in outside it works. But In firefox it fails. Why? How to resolve it?

Comment: the issue is that different browsers choose to call event handlers in different orders.

Comment: It may be the reason, but i need a solution for this issue.

Comment: What is the purpose of needing `blur` to trigger on a key event? If you need that specific behavior, you can reproduce it in Firefox using a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The following demo will show this behavior using Chrome or Firefox:

- When user attempts to type into the `<input>`, the `<label>` that wraps around `<input>` becomes `display:none`.

  - If an event fires from `<input>`, it should be an event that loses focus (ex. `blur`, `focusout`, `change`...). Whatever it is, the callback function should log two items to the console:

    1. `called`
    2. `<body></body>` // as activeElement **[bug 452307](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452307)**

Firefox fails to fire on `blur` event, but it does fire on the `input`event. In the demo, there is a custom function called: `addListener()` which can register multiple events on a single node. This function registers the `blur` and `input` on the `<input>`.

### Demo

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #box {
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='form'>
    <fieldset id='box'>
      <input id='key' type="text" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script>
    var ui = document.forms[0].elements;
    var box = ui.box;
    var key = ui.key;

    box.addEventListener('keydown', closeBox);

    function closeBox(e) {
      e.target.style.display = 'none';
    }

    addListeners(key, 'input blur', triggerOnExit);

    function triggerOnExit(e) {
      console.log('called');
      console.log(document.activeElement);
    }

    function addListeners(node, list, callBack) {
      list.split(' ').forEach(function(e) {
        node.addEventListener(e, callBack);
      });
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that different browsers choose to call event handlers in different orders. SP the easiest soution will be check activElement on your OnWrapperClose method

```
var a = document.getElementById('blur');
function onWrapperClose(e) {
                        document.getElementById('Wrapper').style.display = 'none';
                        console.log(document.activeElement);

                    if(document.activeElement === a){
// do what you wanted to do on blur function   
                }
```

You can strore 
On Firefox it gives activeElemnt as  while on Chrome you get body tag, may be you wanto to add parent div for easier debugging.

Comment: I will not get document.activeElement as body in this case. Input will be remain as active element ever.

Comment: Run the same code with same steps that you have given, it is giving active elemnt as body

Comment: or we can try one more thing, add a parent div and see if we get onfocus